# Sum Between Dates in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

The code in here is not working on the process in `totaldate` as I checked it didn't subtract from `date1` and `date2` but they already got their values such as

`Text1 = 2/10/2019`

`Text2 = 2/8/2019`

I am trying to subtract two dates from two Text box `Text1` and `Text2`, I've already make sure that their format is short date.

I did make it just `totaldate = Text1 - Text2` but it didn't work either

```
Sub tgl()
    date1 = Text1
    date2 = Text2
    totaldate = date1 - date2
    fine = totaldate * 50
End Sub
```

In this output when summing up all of the date and it will got 2 days left as you subtract `Text1` and `Text2` and then you multiply by `50` so you'll get the value for variable `fine = 100`

Comment: What is the 'specific' error message you are recieving?  I can see a couple of different things going wrong here depending. `date1 = Text1` should likely fail(or really just return "") because its not referencing the sheet aka should be `date1 = FormNameHere.Text1BoxNameHere.Value` .  Its also helpful if you dim your variables in advance to ensure that they don't get mistakenly converted.  `Dim date1 as date` etc.  Afterwards, if both are in fact dates, you can subtract them and you will get `2` as expected.

Comment: There is no error message is just that I didn't get any value from the `totaldate` when i'm executing one per line, but there is the value in both `date1` and `date2` but when I'm subtracting those it went to blank instead for the `totaldate`value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates in MS Access are stored as the number of days elapsed since midnight on 30th December 1899, with the time component represented as a fraction of a day in decimal format, e.g.:

```vb
?cdate(1.5)
31/12/1899 12:00:00
```

If your date values have no time component, then simply subtracting the two date values will indeed yield the number of days separating the two dates:

```vb
?#2019-02-10#-#2019-02-08#
 2
```

If, however, your datetime values also have a time component, then performing a basic subtraction of two values will yield a double as opposed to an integer value:

```vb
?#2019-02-10 09:30#-#2019-02-08 07:00#
 2.10416666667152
```

Therefore, you'll need to either using the `DateDiff` function, specifying an interval of `days`, or use the `DateValue` function to return the date component of the datetime value:

```vb
?DateDiff("d",#2019-02-08 07:00#,#2019-02-10 09:30#)
 2
```

```vb
?DateValue(#2019-02-10 09:30#)-DateValue(#2019-02-08 07:00#)
 2
```

With this in mind, you might consider changing your Sub to something along the lines of the following (assuming this is defined within your Form Module in which the variables `Text1` & `Text2` are within scope):

```vb
Sub tgl()
    Dim fine As Long
    fine = (DateValue(Text1) - DateValue(Text2)) * 50
End Sub
```

This will also account for if your `Text1` & `Text2` values are strings as opposed to date values.

Comment: Thanks I just made some variable as Date and then it can finally sum it up

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateDiff` function

```
DateDiff("d", date1 , date2)
```